# Beginner with SwiftUI: VStack with Form and List

Tags: list, forms, swiftui, vstack

I am a beginner with SwiftUI Layout (not in coding) and I have a problem

[image]

Here the code:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Nome", text: $name)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Aggiungi Dispensa", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Aggiungi") {
                if self.name.count > 0 {
                    let item = DispItem(name: self.name)
                    self.dispense.items.append(item)
                }
                self.name = ""
            })
            
            List {
                let sortedItems = dispense.items.sorted {
                    $0.name < $1.name
                }
                ForEach(sortedItems) { item in
                            Text(item.name)
                                .font(.headline)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: removeItems)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically is a VStack composed by Form and List
But I do not understand where the empty space at the top comes from and the white space between Form and List.

Thanks
Marco

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62382165/12299030? And next about empty space https://stackoverflow.com/a/64838243/12299030.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Asperi points out in the links in his comment, you can use `VStack(spacing: 0)` to remove the space between the `Form` and `List`.

For the space between the navigation bar link and title, it looks like you are nesting `NavigationView` items inside each other.

The view that calls this view (is it called "Impostazione"?) has a `NavigationView` so your child view ("Aggiungi Dispensa") doesn't need its own `NavigationView`

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks a lot. But I forgot to link an image: https://imgur.com/8VIJ7Wy

Comment: Empty space I meant before the navigationbartitle and the navigation link to go back

Comment: @MarcoGT try putting the `.navigationBarTitle("Aggiungi Dispensa", displayMode: .inline)` inside the NavigationLink of the previous View

Comment: @MarcoGT I updated my answer (again) - you are nesting `NavigationView` items. If you had a `NavigationView` in the view before this one, you don't need another one.

Comment: @aheze, sorry, I don't get it, what do you mean? I do not have any NavigationLink

Comment: @MarcoGT in the parent view (the view before this one - ImpostazioniView). @JohnNimis is right, you won't need to have another `NavigationView`.